# Pades LTV verification in itextsharp throws The Uri Prefix is not Recognized

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have successfully signed a pdf with LTV support. I can check the pdf and LTV signature is valid through Adobe Acrobat Reader and also with an external validator.

I'm trying to make the same validation with iTextSharp 5.5.10.

I'm following the iText sample code [C5_06](https://github.com/itext/i5ns-tutorial/blob/60090cbd1ac63f4257e419754293894475fb2eaf/signatures/chapter5/C5_06_ValidateLTV/C5_06_ValidateLTV.cs.)

But when I call to `ltvVerifier.Verify`, I am getting a `System.NotSupportedException, The Uri Prefix is not Recognized`. I am loading the certificate used to sign the pdf en cert parameter.

Validation code:

```
   public static bool Validate(byte[] pdfIn, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn))
        {
            var fields = reader.AcroFields;
            var signames = fields.GetSignatureNames();

            if (!signames.Any(n => fields.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(n)))
                throw new Exception("None signature covers all document");

            var verifications = signames.Select(n => fields.VerifySignature(n));

            var invalidSignature = verifications.Where(v => !v.Verify());
            var invalidTimeStamp = verifications.Where(v => !v.VerifyTimestampImprint());

            if (invalidSignature.Any())
                throw new Exception("Invalid signature found");
        }

        using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn))
        {
            var ltvVerifier = new LtvVerifier(reader)
            {
                OnlineCheckingAllowed = false,
                CertificateOption = LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                Certificates = GetChain(cert).ToList(),
                VerifyRootCertificate = false,
                Verifier = new MyVerifier(null)
            };

            var ltvResult = new List<VerificationOK> { };
            ltvVerifier.Verify(ltvResult);

            if (!ltvResult.Any())
                throw new Exception("Ltv verification failed");
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Auxiliary function that builds a List of X509Certificates from the certificate chain:

```
    private static X509.X509Certificate[] GetChain(X509Certificate2 myCert)
    {
        var x509Chain = new X509Chain();
        x509Chain.Build(myCert);

        var chain = new List<X509.X509Certificate>();
        foreach(var cert in x509Chain.ChainElements)
        {
            chain.Add(
                DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert.Certificate)
                );
        }

        return chain.ToArray();
    }
```

A custom verifier, just copied from sample:

```
 class MyVerifier : CertificateVerifier
{
    public MyVerifier(CertificateVerifier verifier) : base(verifier) { }

    override public List<VerificationOK> Verify(
        X509.X509Certificate signCert, X509.X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(signCert.SubjectDN + ": ALL VERIFICATIONS DONE");
        return new List<VerificationOK>();
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant stack trace:

```
  in System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   in System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.CrlVerifier.GetCrl(X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert)
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.CrlVerifier.Verify(X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.OcspVerifier.Verify(X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.LtvVerifier.Verify(X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime sigDate)
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.LtvVerifier.VerifySignature()
   in iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.LtvVerifier.Verify(List`1 result)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? It looks like the location of the CRL for some certificate is not given as an URL which `System.Net.WebRequest` supports.

Comment: @mkl, please find the PDF in the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGvNZY_rGbVRlV5blZFOV9jZ2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `Validate` cannot be compiled - **"not all code paths return a value"**. Actually none does.

Comment: Which `X509Certificate2` do you feed into `Validate`?

Comment: From the PDF signature, the certificate contains this CRLDistributionPoints extension:<br/>            `X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: <br/>
                Full Name:<br/>
                  URI:ldap://ldapcomp.cert.fnmt.es/CN=CRL1,OU=AC%20Componentes%20Informaticos,O=FNMT-RCM,C=ES?certificateRevocationList;binary?base?objectclass=cRLDistributionPoint<br/>
                  URI:http://www.cert.fnmt.es/crlscomp/CRL1.crl`

Comment: @jruizaranguren Did you really want to start a bounty here or did you actually mean your yet unanswered follow-up question [Pades LTV verification in iTextSharp throws Public key presented not for certificate signature for root CA certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41548918/1729265)?

Comment: @mkl, Damn, You are right.

Comment: @mkl, If I add another bounty to that question do you think I will receive some attention? BTW I am glad you receive 50 extra reputation points, your answer was very useful for us.

Comment: @jruizaranguren I will look into that other question; I planned to do so anyways, I still have starred it as a reminder. I cannot promise a point in time, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the certificates in the signer certificate chain present two URIs for CRL download, first a ldap URI and then a http URI, cf. @Egl's comment to your question, but that iText assumes it can simply take the first given URI and use `System.Net.WebRequest` to request its content.

Unfortunately `WebRequest` out-of-the-box only supports http:, https:, ftp:, and file: (cf. [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0aa3d588(v=vs.110).aspx)). Thus, it fails iText's attempt to request the CRL via ldap with an `Exception` which iText doesn't catch.

You can make this work by

- either registering a ldap `WebRequest` handler (cf. [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix(v=vs.110).aspx)).

  Caveat: While the msdn pages suggest that doing something like this is possible, I have not yet done it. Furthermore the OP could not easily follow this path. Thus, there might be restrictions beyond what the msdn documentation describes. Probably only *web*-ish protocols (ftp:, file:, http:, https:) can be used?
- Or changing the iText verifiers (either actually changing iText classes or copying/deriving one's own `CrlVerifier` and `LtvVerifier` variants) to use the http-URI.

  This can either be implemented by catching such exceptions and then continuing with the next CRL request URI or (as done by the OP) by ignoring the ldap URI altogether (filtering it in `CertificateUtil.GetCRLURL`).

Comment: 1st Approach. I register a ldap handler via WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("ldap://", new MyWebRequest()), where MyWebRequest simply make a call to WebRequest.Create(uri). It stills reject the "ldap" prefix. No idea how this could be circumvented.

Comment: 2nd Approach. I have created custom copies MyLtvVerifer, MyCrlVerifier. The only piece that must be changed is the call to CertificateUtil.GetCRLURL in CrlVerifier. It retrieves the first Crl Uri found so I filter out any Uri starting with "ldap://". With that change, I avoid the Uri Prefix error. Unfortunately, I get a new error validating the CA certificate, but I guess that will be another question (Org.BouncyCastle.Security.InvalidKeyException: Public key presented not for certificate signature).

Comment: mkl, thanks for the suggestions. Do my comments make sense to you? If guess I will have to stick with the hacky second option.

Comment: @jruizaranguren I admittedly have not played around with `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`. Thus, I cannot give hints on how exactly to do it correctly. But the second option does not sound that bad anyways. And yes, the `InvalidKeyException` sounds like a different issue altogether.

Comment: I would like to mark this response as answer, but perhaps it would be preferable to add the metioned "caveats": the RegisterPrefix has not been tested for ldap, and the second approach requires modification of LtvVerifier, CrlVerifier and provide an alternate CertificateUtil.GetCRLURL.

Comment: @jruizaranguren I improved the answer along those lines. Alternatively you could have edited it accordingly.

Comment: Second issue added in new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548918/pades-ltv-verification-in-itextsharp-throws-public-key-presented-not-for-certifi